# Text interpolation is showing the wrong result

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();    

Text(
      '$_nameController, seu IMC é ${_result.toStringAsFixed(1)}',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
```

Why is my prompt showing like this:

[Prompt shown by the Text() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvXsy.png)

By the looks of it I figured that the problem is due to the $_nameController bit, but where is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing out the `TextEditingController` object and not the contents of the controller. Instead, do this:

```dart
final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();    

Text(
      '${_nameController.text}, seu IMC é ${_result.toStringAsFixed(1)}',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
```